# different div class js selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the difference between

```
     $('<div/>', {'class': 'name'})
```

and

```
     $('.name-number-field')
```

I have read about selectors before but have never seen the first one before

Answer (score 2):

That first selector is creating a `div` element and assigning the class of `name` to it.

Comment: ok if I wanted to add text inside the created div would I do : $('</div> hi </div>', {'class':'name'})?

Comment: oh great, thank you. What about if I want to add another div inside that newly created div?

Answer (score 0):

The first one will create a brand new div that has a class of name: `<div class='name' />`

The second line is a selector that will look for existing elements with a class of `name-number-field`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div/>', {'class': 'name'})
```

this will create a div element with class = "Name"

While `$('.name-number-field')` will return the element having `name-number-field` class